# Passar como parâmetro a "visibilidade"

Tags: java, android

Como faço pra passar como parâmetro uma visibilidade e depois setar ela?

Ex:

```
private void _setVisibility(View.VISIBLE a){
    _viewLineStatus.setVisibility(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O parâmetro do método [`setVisibility`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) da classe `View`, é `int`. e tem os seguintes possíveis valores:

```
View.VISIBLE = 0x00000000
View.INVISIBLE = 0x00000004
View.GONE = 0x00000008
```

Logo no seu método basta fazer com que a assinatura aceite um `int`, dessa forma:

```
private void _setVisibility(int visibility) {
    _viewLineStatus.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

Se quiser pode até fazer um tratamento para não setar um valor inválido, dado que a classe `View` não faz tratamento:

```
private void _setVisibility(int visibility) {
    if(visibility != View.VISIBLE && visibility != View.INVISIBLE && visibility != View.GONE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Deve passar um desses valores: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE ou View.GONE");
    }

    _viewLineStatus.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Isso mesmo que eu queria.